# examples of c++ code with application to quant finance

Tags: programming

I've some intermediate knowledge in C++. However, the knowledge is more of a theoretical nature and not applied to quant finance problems. I'm looking for good sources,

- code examples
- books
- blogs

to get a feeling how C++ is used in quantitative finance. I implemented some of the models by myself to get used to it. However, it would be nice to compare it with a more experienced source.

Comment: I wish this question was not put on hold as I would benefit from it too. I recommend http://www.amazon.co.uk/Numerical-Methods-Finance-Mastering-Mathematical/dp/0521177162 as a good text.

Comment: @fushsialatitude thanks for the book I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Look at  [QuantLib](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuantLib) .  Introductory slides are available at http://quantlib.org/slides/dima-ql-intro-1.pdf and http://quantlib.org/slides/dima-ql-intro-2.pdf .

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. I thought about quantlib before. I will definitley give it a try